# use php to add html header and footer section to a particular page

Tags: php, html, css

i have two php pages called header.php and footer.php.They will be used to add header and footer to every page i have. So that i only have to include them with every page.But the problem is when i try to add content in the mid section it goes directly under the header section.what is the reason for this behaviour?

Here in this particular code the h1 tag is not visible.It goes under the header portion.

index.php:

```
<?php
   include('header.php');
?>
   <h1>This is my page</h1>
 <?php
   include('footer.php');
 ?>
```

header.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='head'>
   <span ><a href='#' id='top'>MyPHP</a></span>
   <ul id='huls'>
      <li><a href='#'>home</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Log in</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>About us</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

footer.php:

```
<div id='footer'>
   <div id='col1' class='fdiv'>
       <ul>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div >
       <div id='col2' class='fdiv'>
       <ul>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div >
       <div id='col3' class='fdiv'>
       <ul>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
       <div id='col4' class='fdiv'>
       <ul>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>faq</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
   *{
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
   }
    span{
       position:relative;
       display:inline;
       left:20px;
       float:left;

   }
    #head{
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:70px;
        background:skyblue;
        top:0px;
        clear:both;
    }
    #huls li{
       float:right;
       margin-right:30px;
       list-style-type:none;
    }
    #huls a{
       font-size:23px;
       color:white;
       text-decoration:none;
    }
    span #top{
       font-size:35px;
       text-decoration:none;
       color:white;

    }  
     #footer{
         width:100%;
         height:170px;
         position:absolute;
         background:crimson;
         bottom:10px;
      }
      .fdiv{

         width:24%;
         height:100%;
         position:relative;
         float:left;

         text-align:center;

      }
      #footer a{
        text-decoration:none;
        color:white;
        font-size:17px;
      }
      #footer li{
        list-style-type:none;
      }
```

Comment: Instead of <h1> try to use <div> and check

Comment: h1 is a block element and div is also a block element.So what's the difference?

Comment: Can you add the generated HTML part of the `h1` using the source on the browser

Answer (score 2):

Remove `position:absolute;` on `#head` and it works.

Comment: it works ,thanks. But can you explain why it is like that?

Comment: read this article for the difference: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/